# Adding links to a reference list as mentioned in a PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I am looking for a program that can add links to a reference list as mentioned in a PDF.

For example, if the PDF contains:

[image]

It should add clickable hyperlinks to the corresponding research articles.

Any OS, any license, any price is fine. CLI or GUI.

Links can be added in different ways:

[image]

(which was generated using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{foo2010,
  author = "Foo Bar",
  journal = "J.P.B.",
  year = 2010,
  title = "Where the wild things are.",
  doi = {10.1.1/jpb001},
  url = {http://doai.io/10.1038/nature14260}
}

@inproceedings{dblp,
             author = {Jeffrey Dean and
             Sanjay Ghemawat},
             title     = {MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters},
             booktitle = {OSDI},
             year      = {2004},
             note        = {\href{http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html}{(link)}},
             bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
             }

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100782/add-a-hyperlink-in-bibtex
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/osdi/DeanG04,
author    = {Jeffrey Dean and
           Sanjay Ghemawat},
title     = {\href{http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html}{MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters}},
booktitle = {OSDI},
year      = {2004},
ee        = {http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html},
crossref  = {DBLP:conf/osdi/2004},
bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de
}

\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\begin{document}
test \citet{foo2010}
test \citet{DBLP:conf/osdi/DeanG04}
test \citet{dblp}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

but I don't have access to the LaTeX source of the PDFs for which I am trying to add the links)

Comment: Are you just looking for the PDF transformation part, or would the software have to parse the bibliography and search the web for a link to each article as well?

Comment: @Gilles The software would have to parse the bibliography and search the web for a link to each article as well